# Dismiss or pop to root view controller from Popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

My Application has a Sign out button in Pop over on click i want the view controller(not the pop over controller) to Go to root view controller. I created Protocol and to call a method from pop over (MyPopoverViewController) to MyMainViewController. Everything works fine . But when i use pop to root view controller using popToView controller The code doenst have any effect.

```
-(void)LogOut
{
    NSLog(@"This method is called from pop over view controller using Protocol");
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `But when i use pop to root view controller it is not working.` what is not working

Comment: the line   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];  doesnt do anythinng

Comment: print you viewController from navigationController, what is coming ?

Comment: i didnt get you Bhupesh

Comment: You need to call `[self.navigationViewController popToRoot...]` in the viewController presenting the popover.

Comment: even that doesnt work @Allan

Comment: How did you present the viewController presenting the pop over viewcontroller. Did you push it or present modally?

Comment: by seeing code and suggestion i think you should create and upload sample application, it will help us to understand correct scenario  and then you will surely got solution.

Comment: i just created a Seque on the button to pop overview controller and selected POPOVER @Allan

Comment: Can you show the storyboard layout?

Comment: ya ok i will update the question

Comment: I think you're already in the root view controller

Answer (score 1):

This method is called from pop over view controller using Protocol

```
-(void)LogOut
{
    NSLog(@"LogOut");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];

}
```